# Elasticsearch cluster reference

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I have spent quite a time reading forums, manuals and blogs trying to solve the problem of creating elasticsearch cluster reference in couchbase (under XDCR tab).

Finally i decided to raise the problem to the community.

I have:

- Couchbase 4.0.0-4051 Community Edition (build-4051)
- Elasticsearch 2.1.1 with plug-ins:

  - transport-couchbase 2.2.1.2
  - head

Elasticsearch started and uses the following configuration:

- cluster.name: es
- node.name: node-1
- node.master: true
- node.data: true
- couchbase.password: pass
- couchbase.username: root
- couchbase.maxConcurrentRequests: 1024

> [2016-01-20 15:59:19,741][INFO ][transport.couchbase      ] [node-1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9091}

The problem is that i can't create elasticsearch cluster reference in Couchbase web UI under XDCR tab, entering the following information:

- Cluster Name: es
- IP/hostname: 127.0.0.1:9091
- Username: root
- Password: *****

[Cluster reference setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdGAs.png)

After pressing Save, error message appears: "Attention - Unexpected server error, request logged."

Here is the fragment from xdcr.log file

> [xdcr:debug,2016-01-20T16:31:16.848+02:00,ns_1@127.0.0.1<0.419.0>:goxdcr_rest:stats:211]
>   Unable to obtain stats for bucket "beer-sample" from goxdcr:
>
> {error,{badmatch,{error,timeout}},
>          [{goxdcr_rest,send_with_timeout,5,
>                        [{file,"src/goxdcr_rest.erl"},{line,60}]},
>           {goxdcr_rest,query_goxdcr,4,[{file,"src/goxdcr_rest.erl"},{line,132}]},
>           {goxdcr_rest,get_from_goxdcr,3,
>                        [{file,"src/goxdcr_rest.erl"},{line,152}]},
>           {goxdcr_rest,stats,1,[{file,"src/goxdcr_rest.erl"},{line,207}]},
>           {goxdcr_stats_collector,grab_stats,1,
>                                   [{file,"src/goxdcr_stats_collector.erl"},
>                                    {line,37}]},
>           {base_stats_collector,handle_info,2,
>                                 [{file,"src/base_stats_collector.erl"},
>                                  {line,89}]},
>           {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,604}]},
>           {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I did some more research and it was a trivial issue. 
I added the following line to the config/elasticsearch.yml file

> network.host: 192.168.2.108

And after that started the elasticsearch:

> [2016-01-21 10:15:35,524][INFO ][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Fasaud] Resolved publish host:/192.168.2.108
>   [2016-01-21 10:15:35,524][INFO ][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Fasaud] Resolved bind host:/192.168.2.108
>   [2016-01-21 10:15:35,615][INFO ][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Fasaud] Using port(s):9091

And then successfully created elasticsearch cluster reference under couchbase XDCR tab.

[Created Cluster reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV11D.png)

It turns out that you need to specify internal IP address when creating cluster reference from couchbase to the elasticsearch cluster, despite both clusters (couchbase and elasticsearch) are located on the same machine.

Please note that it is not the case with elasticsearch 1.7 and transport-couchbase 2.1.2 plugin, elasticsearch 1.7 uses internal IP by default.

Comment: I spent lot of time on this issue. finally found your answer. Thank you!

Comment: what is the user password you used there? my local dev version doesnt use a password - btw i am behind corporate proxy, can that be an issue connecting local couchbase to local elastic search?